# Getting the Selected Item among items present in Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I am implementing a **Media Player** application using **WPF**. I want to display a List Screen where the user can select the video from a list.

I want to display the videos in a list horizontally(without scrollbars so not using `ListView`) where each item consists of a thumbnail, title and duration.

Now I also want to obtain which item was clicked on so as to play the correct video. I tried to display the items in a `WrapPanel` which sufficed for display but doesnt have a `SelectedIndex` property.

Will a `Grid` be helpful in this regard? If yes then how do I obtain which item was selected in the `Grid`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ListBox`.

WPF UI elements keep their appearance separate from their functionality. If you want a list of items where you can select one, use a `ListBox`. If you want to customize how it looks, simply change its [Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

`Grid`, `WrapPanel`, `StackPanel` and the like are just `Panel` UI element which are used for *Layout*. They don't derive from `Selector` and thus don't have any item selection features.

Since you didn't post any relevant XAML in your question, I'll not post any relevant XAML in my answer.

Comment: Thanks..can 'StackPanels' be added as items of a 'ListBox'?

Comment: in the template they can.